# how to sync and get adobe custom_attributes in api productSearch of Live Search

Tags: livesearch, magento-ee

how can i get custom value(brand) from adobe via graphql
https://commerce.adobe.io/search/graphql
here is my query

```
query productSearch {
  productSearch(phrase: "bag") {
    total_count
    items {
      product {
        name
        sku
        custom_attributes {
          code
          value
        }
      }
    }
    facets {
      title
    }
  }
}
```

headers
{
"Magento-Environment-Id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"Magento-Website-Code": "base",
"Magento-Store-Code": "main_website_store",
"Magento-Store-View-Code": "default",
"X-Api-Key": "search_gql"
}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3dOH.png)

Comment: Did you ever manage to get this working? I'm struggling with similar.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure brand is added to the search index and then you can request through graphQL request. Something like this.

```
query productSearch {
 productSearch(phrase: "bag") {
  total_count
  items {
   product {
    name
    sku
    brand
    custom_attributes {
      code
      value
    }
   }
  }
  facets {
   title
  }
 }
}
```